# Hybrid app using phoneGap to Record video and split every 10min

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to record video on iPhone using phoneGap mediaCapture API, which records and saves it to media files with in the application perfectly if I want to split the video and save recording every 10 minutes so as develop a dash cam application.

I tried this code which records for 10 minutes and automatically stops but actually I want this happen every time 10min continuously 5 times as i set limit to 5.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#rec").click(function(){ 
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) 
{
  var i, path, len; 
  for (i = 0,len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) 
  { 
    path =mediaFiles[i].fullPath; // do something interesting with the file 
   }
};
```

// capture error callback

```
var captureError = function(error) {
navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'CaptureError'); 
};
```

// start video capture

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {
limit:5, duration:600 });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just start another `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(.. ..)` in the `captureSuccess` callback handler

The easiest way would be to put the original one in a function and call that function in the `captureSuccess` function

Comment: Perfectly working ...Thank you so much ....sorry for the late reply but if i want to restart the camera capture function, instead of pressing the button how do i do that ?

Comment: listen for the event you want to trigger it and call the function which starts the capture

Comment: I am sorry couldn't understand

Comment: What would you want to trigger the capture other than the button press, find the event which is caused by that action and call the function you call when the button is pressed

Comment: I actually have no idea of triggering any function from xcode using java script can you please, please help me out.

Comment: you need to figure out what you want to cause it to start capturing then look for a callback that fires when that event happens to the device. I don't have any experience in using phoneGap just general programming and javascript/jQuery so  don't know the api at all